# How do I tell gdb how long my zero-length array is?

Tags: c, xcode, debugging, gcc, gdb

Slightly oxymoronic title! Bonus points for Xcode answer but it's a gdb question.

If I have a standard, statically sized array gdb will print all its elements [and Xcode will let me browse through it] but if I have a [zero length array](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length), it won't, because it doesn't know. Obviously I can print the array indexes one by one, but I'd like a dump of the whole thing.

How do I tell gdb how much space I have allocated for the array to allow it to print the array (or to allow Xcode to view the array). Is it even possible?

Comment: Doesn't seem to really relate to programming, but his Usenet signature used to say "Uncle Bob" (with the quotes). For example: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.object/msg/34e0d53f2235bd93?hl=en

Comment: Why the close vote? Let me quote from the FAQ:`*  a specific programming problem
    * a software algorithm
    * software tools commonly used by programmers
    * matters that are unique to the programming profession
`

Comment: And whose Usenet signature used to say "uncle bob"? I think someone's voting on the wrong question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_9.html#SEC54

Discusses "Artificial arrays"

> It is often useful to print out several successive objects of the same type in memory;...

Answer (score 3):

If `s->a` has type `char [0]` (which is a gcc extension), but you know it is really an array of 100, you can use casts in `gdb` to print it:

```
(gdb) print *(char (*)[100])&s->a
```

Answer (score 2):

See [`10.4 Artificial Arrays`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Arrays.html#Arrays):

```
(gdb) p *argv@argc
```